# Angularjs populate select options with json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, select, populate

I am looking to populate select option with values from a basic json array.

The example I have is a country select.  Each country has an id element and a name plus other fields that I can ignore.  Basically I would like to say put one value in the `value=""` field and another between the `<option>tags</option>`

**html snippet**

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">

  <p>populate select options with ajax</p>

    <select id="Country" name="Country" class="form-control" size="10" 
        ng-model ="chooseCountries">                                
            <option ng:repeat="country in chooseCountries" value="{{country.id}}">     
                {{country.name}}
            </option>
    </select>

</div>
```

**javascript snippet**

```
'use strict';

function DemoSelectCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.chooseCountries=[
        {countryId : 1, name : "France - Mainland", desc: "some description" },
        {countryId : 3, name : "Gibraltar", desc: "some description"},
        {countryId : 3, name : "Malta", desc: "some description"}
    ];  

});
```

I have put it together here **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e31k5e6L/)**..  I think I'm missing something

Comment: change the value of option `value="{{country.countryId}}"`

Comment: It is better advised to use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap'])` - be sure you have ui.bootstrap. Read how to install it http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
2. Here is your updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e31k5e6L/1/

Comment: what is this line doing? `$scope.selectedCountry = angular.copy($scope.chooseCountries[0]);`

Comment: It's just default value for $scope.selectedCountry (you can remove this line if you don't want to use default value). In this case angular.copy creates copy of first element of chooseCountries array.  So it means $scope.selectedCountry =  {countryId : 1, name : "France - Mainland", desc: "some description" };

Answer (score 3):

In this above example you are missing `value` attribute change this `value="{{country.countryId}}"`. try this

```
<select id="Country" name="Country" class="form-control" size="10" ng-model ="chooseCountries">                                
    <option ng:repeat="country in chooseCountries" value="{{country.countryId}}">
        {{country.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

and see the example [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/coverbeck/FxM3B/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You miss-typed the `value` attribute, change it to `country.countryId`.

Also, set `ng-model` directive to a single countryId value (or array of country IDs) instead of the full object.

```
<select id="Country" name="Country" ng-model ="selectedValue"> 
    <option ng:repeat="country in chooseCountries" value="{{country.countryId}}">
        ...
```

JS:

```
function DemoSelectCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.selectedValue = 1;    

    $scope.chooseCountries=[
        {countryId : 1, name : "France - Mainland", desc: "some description" },
        {countryId : 3, name : "Gibraltar", desc: "some description"},
        {countryId : 3, name : "Malta", desc: "some description"}
    ];  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to populate a standard select(you can use [angular-ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) too) with objects is to use "ng-options" directive and "ng-repeat" using "track by id" ([see AngularJS doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)), this works well with ng-model. This is an example of how to use it:

```
<select id="select_field" name="select_field"
   ng-model="vm.selectedCountry"
   ng-options="country as country.name for country in vm.chooseCountries track by country.countryId">
   <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
</select>
```

I must say that "vm" is in case of "controllerAs" defined in the controller, if you use the $scope directly, you can remove the "vm".

This is the best way that I found to populate a select field.