# Fill HTML select with options from Web.config

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an HTML page, with a `<select>` which has a few options in it. Currently, these options are hardcoded into the HTML.

Is there a way to get a list of options in Web.config, get them in my AngularJS controller, and populate the `<select>`?

Comment: You could create a settings file under your project properties and then they would be accessible in a singleton (which you can override in your app config or web config)

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want following those steps :

1. Load your options from the Web.config file : [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854777/read-variable-from-web-config)
2. Create a ViewModel to represents your `select` options
3. Create a new endpoint to `GET` this ViewModel : [how](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-awesome-guide-on-how-to-build-restful-apis-with-asp-net-core-87b818123e28)
4. Populate your options in your AngularJS application : [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636237/angularjs-populate-select-options-with-json)

All of that is basic and it's easy to find more information to achieve what you need.
 Hope it helps.